# Detect invoker of startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I have many buttons on an activity, all of them invoke same activity by using following code

`startActivityForResult()`

Results are caught in

`void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`.

How do I know with button return result?

Comment: change requestCode for every button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change `requestCode` for every `Button` . You can use, for instance, as `RequestCode` the id of the `button`. When onActivityResult is called,

```
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch(requestCode) {
   case R.id.button1:
    break;
   }
}
```

you can switch on `requestCode`, ad case for the `buttonId`

Comment: Thanks. Can I pass an object in `Intent`?

Comment: yes but it havs to implement Serializable. And you should use a Bundle. Take a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29